# Почему не подключается телефон в качестве эмулятора к Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Скачал Google USB Driver, есть режим разработчика и отладка по USB но в студии не отображается подключенные устройства. Как исправить неполадку ?

Comment: Гугл по этому поводу молчит?

Comment: google USB driver в основном для Nexus-устройств (гугловских устройств). Вам нужно установить драйвер для своей модели